# How to optimize the execution of query that takes too long

Tags: mariadb, index-tuning, mariadb-10.1

I am working with a query that is taking around 53 minutes to execute, which I feel is excessive.

Maria DB version: *Server version: 10.1.38-MariaDB-1~stretch mariadb.org*

The declaration of the relevant base table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `callinfo` (
  `uniqueid` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `callerid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `sip_from_user` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `sip_from_host` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `sip_from_uri` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sip_via_host` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `callednum` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `billseconds` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trunk_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trunkip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `callerip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `disposition` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `debit` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `cost` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `provider_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pricelist_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `package_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pattern` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `invoiceid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rate_cost` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `reseller_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reseller_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `reseller_code_destination` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reseller_cost` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `provider_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `provider_code_destination` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `provider_cost` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `provider_call_cost` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL,
  `call_direction` enum('outbound','inbound') NOT NULL,
  `calltype` enum('STANDARD','DID','FREE','CALLINGCARD') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'STANDARD',
  `profile_start_stamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `answer_stamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `bridge_stamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `progress_stamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `progress_media_stamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `end_stamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `billmsec` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `answermsec` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `waitmsec` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `progress_mediamsec` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flow_billmsec` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_recording` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0 for On,1 for Off',
  `call_reward_amount` decimal(20,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  UNIQUE KEY `uniqueid` (`uniqueid`),
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `pattern` (`pattern`,`notes`),
  KEY `callerid` (`callerid`),
  KEY `sipuri` (`sip_from_uri`),
  KEY `call_direction` (`call_direction`),
  KEY `callednum` (`callednum`),
  KEY `date` (`date`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `group_by` (`date`,`customer_id`,`pattern`,`notes`,`callerid`,`sip_from_uri`,`call_direction`,`callednum`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `date_user_callednum` (`date`,`customer_id`,`callerid`,`callednum`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `date_callednum` (`date`,`callednum`,`callerid`,`sip_from_uri`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `date_user` (`date`,`customer_id`,`callerid`,`sip_from_uri`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `date_direction` (`date`,`call_direction`,`callednum`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `callinfo_report` (`date`,`type`,`reseller_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `select_callinfo_report` (`uniqueid`,`billseconds`,`calltype`,`debit`,`cost`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='callinfo';
```

This table contains over 10 million rows with ~2k added every hour.

The query at issue is the one below:

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(uniqueid) AS attempts, 
              AVG(billseconds) AS acd, MAX(billseconds) AS mcd,
              SUM(billseconds) AS duration, 
              SUM(CASE WHEN calltype !='free' THEN billseconds ELSE 0 END) as billable, 
              SUM(CASE WHEN billseconds > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as completed, 
              SUM(debit) AS debit, SUM(cost) AS cost, 
               (SUM(debit)-SUM(cost)) as profit, 
              round(SUM(CASE WHEN billseconds > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(uniqueid), 2) AS asr 
    FROM (`callinfo`) 
    WHERE `date` >=  '2017-03-01 00:00:00' 
      AND `date` <=  '2019-04-01 23:59:59' 
      AND `reseller_id` =  0 
      AND `type` IN ('0', '3')  
    GROUP BY `customer_id` 
    ORDER BY `customer_id` desc 
    LIMIT 10;
```

I know, I have set up too much indexes here, but I am not sure which one is working.

Below is explain extended output for the above query:

```
+------+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                                                                              | key         | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | cdrs  | index | date,group_by,date_user_callednum,date_callednum,date_user,date_direction,callinfo_report  | customer_id | 7       | NULL | 690765 |   100.00 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

Does anyone like to point out any root cause for the slow execution?

Comment: ``date` datetime` **Very** bad idea calling your field name after an SQL keyword! I would change this to `call_time` and I would have a field named `call_date DATE` because in your query you have `WHERE `date` >=  '2017-03-01 00:00:00' AND `date` <=  '2019-04-01 23:59:59'` and you're making no use of the time part and indexing it is an extra burden. Or you could use a generated column? Or a function based index - both of which are available in MariaDB AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for point Versace, But as you suggested I had changed original field name so no worry about it. Right now i have some time where I can change the entire structure of this table so i just did.

Comment: Put a comment here for my attention (put @ in front of my handle) to let me know if the `DATE` thing works out!

Comment: @Vérace Nope,It not worked :(. Still consume a long time.

Comment: And a +1 for a very good first question! Provide the plan for the query!

Comment: Thanks for understanding that as am work as a beginner. Will you please tell how to share plan for the query? but I can share the information which I understand. Using GUI user can change call_date,customer_id, pattern, notes,trunk_id which may append in where clause.User can add HOUR(call_date),MONTH(call_date),DAY(call_date),YEAR(call_date),customer_id,(pattern,note),caller id,sip_from_uri ,call_direction,callednum may add in group by clause.

Comment: Hmm... it's a bit sad that MySQL doesn't have better output for `EXPLAIN`! I could recommend that you change to PostgreSQL? Now, though, what you **can** do is to go through any and all possible combinations of indexes. You also have to realise that your system may just have to be slow - i.e. there's nothing more that you can do? If you have HDDs, you could upgrade to SSDs? Or expand horizontally? Or  have your OLTP system completely separate from your OLAP (which is what this query is AFAICS) system. You have many options, but a solution will require work!

Comment: Thanks verace,For a suggestion, I hope I am able to change to PostgreSQL.But at this level of web application its more tedious job for me. But let me try more and more option of index and check out.

Comment: Did you really want a range of 2 years + 1 month + 1 day?

Comment: How many different customer_ids?

Comment: Where does `uniqueid` come from?  Something you generate?  Some program generates it?  `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  Do other tables need to reference it?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: I suspect that the query you gave is not the only important query; please provide some others.  The one you provide does not make much sense (last 10 customer ids), so I don't want to confuse you by optimizing it.

Comment: @RickJames  Thank you so much for reply. Actually this table is accessible by 9 different different reports.In which summary reports can search/Group by  with customer_id,callerid,sip_from_uri,trunk_id,disposition,date,provider_id,(pattern,notes),call_direction,calltype,But all reports have different option in search from above specified. Each report will execute three queries 1.Get number of rows after apply search/Group by condition 2. Get list of rows with limit query 3. Get total value after apply search/Group by condition

Comment: Right now,I have added 33 indexes to manage all these reports may be this is wrong but i dont have enough knowledge how can i optimize so i tried this way.

Comment: Regarding Customer_ids right now around 100,000 And after some time it will move around 1,000,000 . Regarding innodb_buffer_pool_size(1GB), RAM : 32GB with 40 core

Comment: @AnkitDoshi - Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of _available_ RAM.  (But not so big that swapping occurs.)

Comment: @AnkitDoshi - 33 indexes is a lot.  9 reports is not many; usually I find that I can have one summary table handling a "few" reports.  So, I would predict fewer than 9 summary tables are needed.  The benefit is that the big fetch and `GROUP BY` is mostly done every hour or night, allowing the actual reporting to be much faster.    See: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: @RickJames: I go through your post but the client is not happy to do make a summary report every hour/day/month. So what I am thinking that I have one detail and one summary for the same data. It will be good to create one more table(callinfo_customer) which is using for single detail/summary report. Apply all the indexes which are required for this report on that table(callinfo_customer). Using trigger am going to insert a record into a callinfo_customer table. I can combine 4 reports into 2 tables(single table using for one summary/single).Please suggest any better way if you have.

Comment: @AnkitDoshi - A cron job (or trigger or other technique) keeps the Summary _table_ up to date.  From it, the client can write a variety of _reports_, either canned or ad hoc, at will.  A Summary table is usually made for only one time unit; other units can be derived from it (via sum(sums) and sum(counts)).

Comment: @AnkitDoshi - (continued) The particular `SELECT` suggests a Summary table with day, customer_id, reseller_id, and type as the `PRIMARY KEY`, with several `SUMs`, a few `COUNTs`, but no `AVG` -- it is computed by `SUM(sums)/SUM(counts)`.  That way, the user can plug in any start and end date and get the desired results.  No need to build a separate Summary table for different date ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You need an index like `(customer_id, reseller_id, type, date)` because those columns are used for result restriction, grouping and sorting. Keep in mind that the same query with different timeranges and/or type lists can require the different index.

Comment: I see, Still it's showing the customer_id as a key in Explain query output.

Comment: Once the Optimizer hits `date` and sees that there is a "range" on `date`, it will stop using the index.  Move `date` to later.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for noticing that! I've edited my answer.

Comment: @RickJames Also when all conditions are ranges optimizer can use an index. Say if data is an N-dimentional OLAP-cube and we want to cut some section with ranges on all dimensions: `SELECT AVG(val) FROM cube WHERE ts BETWEEN ts1 AND ts2 AND x BETWEEN x1 AND x2 AND y BETWEEN y1 AND y2 ...` - optimizer will use `(ts, x, y ...)`.

Comment: @Kondybas - I disagree... I claim that (in your example), it will use only ts and not promptly filter on the other columns. The 'proof' can be had with judicious use of `SHOW SESSION STATUS`, looking at `Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests`.  Don't be fooled by "Using index condition" in `EXPLAIN`, which implies that the other columns are used -- but only after fetching rows.

Comment: I claim it will fetch _all_ the rows between ts1 and ts2 _then_ check each one to filter on the other columns.  With ICP, this can be done in the InnoDB engine rather than incurring the extra cost of handing the rows up to the "handler".  But, since the biggest cost is fetching rows, ICP is only a partial optimization.